# Automated tests fail in Azure, but the result of the step is a pass, why is that?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a suite of automated API tests that execute on code commit. The automated tests run but a number of them fail as expected. However, the step that executes the tests comes back as successful. Hence, the entire job succeeds, which is incorrect behavior.

[image: The failed tests but passed step and job]

```yaml
parameters:
- name: testScriptDisplayName
  type: string
- name: testScript
  type: string

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    ls -a
  displayName: 'Explore output directory'
  workingDirectory: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/API/API-Tests'

- script: |
    npm install
    npx playwright install --with-deps
  displayName: "npm install"
  workingDirectory: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/API/API-Tests'

- script: |
    ${{ parameters.testScript }}
    ls -a
  displayName: ${{ parameters.testScriptDisplayName }}
  workingDirectory: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/API/API-Tests'
  failOnStderr: true
  continueOnError: false
  env:
    CI: true

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish test results'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    testRunner: JUnit
    testResultsFiles: '**/e2e-junit-results.xml'
    # don't need to use searchFolder
    #searchFolder: 'ts/playwright'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the [failTaskOnFailedTests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-test-results-v2) parameter to the PublishTestResults task, and it will mark the pipeline as failed - but still give you the test report.

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish test results'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    testRunner: JUnit
    testResultsFiles: '**/e2e-junit-results.xml'
    failTaskOnFailedTests: true
```

Comment: Thanks Vince, you rock! That did the trick.